# Code generator (.net)

Tags: .net, code-generation, t4, codesmith

Do you have any experience with [T4](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) and [T4 Editor](http://www.t4editor.net/)? Can you compare it to [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) or [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/)?

What code generators do you use? What do you recommend?

I want to use it for generatig of SPs. Is there anything else you find code generation useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly you are trying to do? I guess it also depends on from where you are trying to generate the code (the model).

The advantage with Codesmith and MyGeneration is, they provide multiple options for you to generate your code - for eg, in MyGeneration, you can write your templates in various langs.

MyGeneration can provide a meta model of any DB and a lot of built in generator scripts - so that if you want to generate SPs, the easiest thing will be to use generators for MyGeneration - you can find generators for CRUD SPs right there. It also provides a reasonably good editor if you want to modify the generators.

If you are building a DSL or something (I mean, the model is coming from some where else), then you might consider using T4. How ever, T4 editing is not the easiest thing I've done, because there is no T4 editing support with in Visual Studio. You might consider purchasing Clarius T4 editor for good editing support.

Comment: The main purpose is to generate CRUD SPs for existing DB tables. But I guess there should be another field where code generators are useful.

Comment: For generating crud sps existing db tables, My Generation should be good as it can expose the entire DB as a model.

Answer (score 3):

As a code generation engine, T4 is as capable as CodeSmith or MyGeneration. It's main advantage is the tight integration in Visual Studio; the main drawback is the smaller number of ready-to-use templates.

I personally prefer the [T4 editor from Tangible](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/04/t4-editor-by-tangible-engineering/) because it works with the [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com).

Oleg

Answer (score 1):

Something that increases your productivity is by using the **inbuilt snippets of Visual Studio**.

`tab tab`

Like typing `if` and pressing tab twice will generate an if statement for you, and then basically you just fill in the blanks

`try` and two tabs will generate a try-catch block

etc...

There is a whole list of snippets which you can make use of.

Comment: Snippets are great but I am looking for a more powerful solution generating code based on specific data (eg., SPs based on database tables).

Comment: Especially since  you can create your own snippets, it may save a lot of time (and repeating actions).

Answer (score 0):

Besides nowadays recommended T4 templates, there is another way to generate code in VS - [MVC Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), which can be used for any code generation (not only ASP.NET MVC).

It is based on T4 but adds some usefull features like template parameters, integration with VS (opening documents, etc.), PowerShell scripting, and multiple files generation.