# Code Generators for .Net

Tags: .net, code-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code generator (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365208/code-generator-net)

I'm looking to do some side projects but don't have the time to hand code everything.  What code generators has anyone used?  Currently, I am looking at Iron Speed, but can't really afford to buy it.  So I'm looking for a product under $300.00.

Any suggestions?

Jim

Answer (score 3):

One of the most well known code generators is codesmith (http://www.codesmithtools.com/). Visual Studio now supports code generation natively via T4 (http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/05/01/visual-studios-t4-code-generation.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) is one option, it can write your classes based off of your db table schema.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your are exactly looking for, but I found these:

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/products/

http://www.codesmithtools.com/store/pricing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted code templates, CodeSmith is pretty much the gold standard.  If you actually want something that can generate code based off of your database model (O/R mapping), there are many good ones.  I use [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/) -- it has a steep learning curve, but the payoff is worth it.  You can have a fully working data access layer and business logic layer in minutes that are easily synced with any database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx). It's free, open source and quite good.